# How do I create a new login on an Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql, sonarqube

I'm trying to install [SonarQube](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarqube/) on Azure, using an Azure SQL Database, which is a serverless database.  Instructions I have found advise me to run these commands from the query editor:

```sql
-- On master
CREATE LOGIN sonarqube WITH PASSWORD = ‘StrongPassword’;

-- On my sonarqube db
CREATE USER sonarqube FOR LOGIN SonarQube WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER sonarqube;

-- Then log in using user sonarqube, then:
ALTER DATABASE sonarqube SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

But the serverless database, and the 'virtual' database server created for it don't have a `master` database. Every search result on this I have found doesn't understand the problem, and the Azure docs are simply very, very bad in this regard.

The docs do hint that only an AD user can add a login and add the `db_owner` role to a user linked to that login, but the clarity and cohesiveness of the docs on this matter are dismal.

How can I achieve the end goal here of a `sonarqube` login, that has a `sonarqube` user with `db_owner` on the `sonarqube` database?

Answer (score 0):

I have a serverless database on that logical server shown below:

[image]

When you connect to that server on management studio, make a click on Options.

[image]

Make sure you connect to the Master database and make a click on Connect.

[image]

Then you will be able to see the master database under the System Databases folder. Make a right click on the master database and select New Query to create a query and execute it.

[image]